# ul Tags> li I want to get the number of tags

Tags: javascript, html

In the source, we want to find the number of `li.q_basket_area` belonging to `ul#side-recent-area`.

<strike>The value displayed in the console log is 3 instead of 5.</strike>

The console outputs 5 correctly.

```
$newAt(".recent_number").text('['+ nodesSameClass +']');
```

In the above case, the value of nodesSameClass is 3.

The style of the `diplaynone` class is `display:none!important;`

Is this affected? What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("side-recent-area");
var nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("q_basket_area");
console.log(nodesSameClass.length);
```

```css
.displaynone {display:none!important;}
```

```html
<span class="recent_number"></span>
<ul id="side-recent-area" class="side-recent-area">
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area displaynone xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area displaynone xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I've converted your code into an executable snippet, and as you can see, the script works and logs `5` to the console. Please [modify](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54050428/edit) the snippet to be a [mcve] which shows the actual problem.

Comment: When I put this in a CodePen, I get a console output of `5`.

Comment: @Andreas The question is wrong.It's corrected. Thank you.

Comment: @AlexandervanOostenrijk The question is wrong.It's corrected. Thank you.

Comment: Please modify the snippet so it shows the actual problem with a [mcve]. And what is with the added script? Where, how and when is it executed?

Comment: @Andreas I will organize and correct it.Thank you for your interest.

Comment: Everything seems normal. You have 5 total elements, but 2 are styled with a 'hidden' class. 3 products are shown in the list on the page, and your console correctly shows 5 elements total.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the result is not wrong. Check Terry's post how to exclude, anything that you do not wish to get as an element. It answers your question exactly.

An alternative as a solution in a single line is by using [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll).

```
var l = document.querySelectorAll( 'ul#side-recent-area li.q_basket_area:not(.displaynone)' ).length;
console.log( l ); // run this to get the result
```

Answer (score 1):

When you select for elements whose class matches `q_basket_area`, JS will return all the nodes regardless of whether they are visible or not. If you want to filter the node collection such that only visible nodes remain, you will need to:

1. Convert the node collection into an array
2. Filter the array, by checking the computed style of the element individually to see if their `display` property is set to `"none"`

In JavaScript, this can be done as follow:

1. Use `Array.prototype.slice.call(<NodeCollection>)` to convert the collection into an array
2. Filter the array by checking the computed `display` property, accessible using `window.getComputedStyle(<YourElement>).display`, and checking if it matches the string `"none"` or not.

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("side-recent-area");
var nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("q_basket_area")

var visibleNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodesSameClass)
   .filter(function(element) {
     return window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none';
  });

console.log(visibleNodes.length);
```

See the snippet below as a proof-of-concept demo:

```js
var parent = document.getElementById("side-recent-area");
var nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("q_basket_area")
  
var visibleNodes = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodesSameClass)
   .filter(function(element) {
     return window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none';
  });

console.log(visibleNodes.length);
```

```css
.displaynone {display:none!important;}
```

```html
<span class="recent_number"></span>
<ul id="side-recent-area" class="side-recent-area">
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area displaynone xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li class="q_basket_area displaynone xans-record-">
        <div class="q_basket_details displaynone">
            <h3 class="q-heading -size-xs">
                <a href="/show/board.html##param##">product</a>
            </h3>
            <ul class="q_basket_info">
                <li class="q_basket_name">
                    <a href="#;" class="displaynone">(eng : )</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

If you are familiar with the ES6 syntax, things get a lot easier:

```js
const parent = document.getElementById("side-recent-area");
const nodesSameClass = parent.getElementsByClassName("q_basket_area")

const visibleNodes = Array.from(nodesSameClass)
   .filter(element => window.getComputedStyle(element).display !== 'none');

console.log(visibleNodes.length);
```

The difference is that:

1. You can use `const` instead of `var`
2. You can use `Array.from` to convert a NodeCollection into an Array
3. You can use arrow functions in the callback of `Array.prototype.filter()` method

Answer (score 1):

You can also use CSS to get the count of list items:

check out: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_counters.asp

```css
li {
 counter-increment: section
}

ul:after {
 content: "Item Count:" counter(section) "";
 margin-top: 2rem;
 display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
 <li>List item.</li>
</ul>
```